# Firestore security rule with get(<path>).id - id prop not available?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am attempting to get the key of a document using the Firestore resource property `id` derived from using `get()`, like so:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/the/$(path)/is/$(request.resource.data.here)).id`

I don't think `id` is available. I have tried a simulation using `exists()` without the  `id` property at the end and it worked, so I know the resource is there and the path is correct.

Here is the piece of Firestore security rule doc I referenced: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

Not sure if the way I try to get the `id` is incorrect or it's just not available?

Comment: I have the same problem, it looks like `id` is not available :(

Comment: did you try .data.id ? - idk if it works